# Limit line output rate in XTerm?

Tags: linux, xterm

I have a problem where my Python script that I want to run in XTerm outputs too many lines simultaneously, which eventually makes the script crash with an error message:

```
close failed in file object destructor:
sys.excepthook is missing
lost sys.stderr
```

How do I limit the line output rate for this to not happen? I read that this was possible in for example tmux [according to this](http://blog.fraggod.net/2014/09/23/tmux-rate-limiting-magic-against-terminal-spamflood-lock-ups.html), but I can't find any option like this for XTerm. Any help?

Comment: Any reason you can't run `tmux` inside your `xterm`, as suggested by the blog to which you linked?

Answer (score 1):

I doubt limiting the rate at which xterm displays the data (reads it from the pseudo-terminal master side) will make any difference here. If anything, it's more likely that the problem be the reverse (that xterm doesn't read fast enough so the pty buffer gets full, so write attempts may block or return with less data written as requested is using non-blocking mode)

You could always pipe the output (and/or error) to `pv -qL1000` to slow the output to 1000 B/s

```
myscript | pv -qL1000
```

Or so that `myscript`'s stdout still be a terminal:

```
socat -u 'exec:myscript,commtype=pty,raw' - | pv -qL1000
```

Comment: I'm getting an error: `socat[16957] E parseopts(): unknown option "commtype"
Usage: purify -view [-flags] {appname | file.pv ...}
  You must specify either an appname or one or more file.pv arguments.` Running socat 1.7.0.0. Commtype seems to have been added in version 2, and there unfortunately is no way for me to update to that version.